# Button being used as a link

Tags: input, semantic-markup

Im maintaining a site I didnt build thats for car insurance. In the banner of every page is an input that takes you to a page with a form to fill out. I cant understand why an input is used instead of a link, is there ever a valid and semantic reason for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Occasionally, people have done this because they want a link that "looks like a button".  However, it is bad design.

It was never a good idea, but in the old days there was at least some justification for it: it gave a button feel and functionality to the link.  However, with modern web design there is no need to do this: the same functionality can be created simply by styling a normal link appropriately.

On the other hand, this is probably more of a style issue than a real problem.  It may not be worth changing it if you are maintaining an existing site.

Answer (score 0):

using `button` or `input type="button"` is the original way to set up an Ajax request. that said, since it's taking the user to another page, sounds like they do not know what they are doing and/or wanted the styles that @dan1111 mentioned